# View for the user followed by the author of a node

Tags: views, flags

I have installed the Flag module, and I have a view that displays how many followers (flags) an author has. How do I reverse that query, and output how many users that author is following?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little tricky, but it is very similar to the article posted at http://drupal.org/node/326580.

- Create a view of users
- Add the "Flags: User flag" relationship making sure that the flags are by **any user**.
- Add the "Flags: User" relationship which will allow us to filter by the person who did the flagging.
- Add a contextual filter (D7) / argument (D6) fir the "User: Uid" and make sure is uses the "Flag user" relationship.
- In contextual filter / argument, select the "Provide default value" option and add the following code snippet to pass the node author as the value.

Code snippet:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  return $node->uid;
}
```

In order to get the count it will depend on whether you are using Drupal 6 or Drupal 7, but using the [Views Group By](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) module for D6 or the internal Aggregation features of D7 should be able to get you the number of users.

Comment: Chris- thanks for the response!  I am using D7.4- can you explain more about what you mean by 'internal aggregation features of D7"? I don't know how to do that.  I have been banging my head against the wall for weeks trying to figure this out!  This is the closest I've seen to any solution.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Likewise- that Views Groupby Module will not install into version 7. It says it is incompatible. There is no version for D7. Any other suggestions?

Comment: ok- I followed this exactly as you say. I have a block I was adding this into that was working as well- showed # of followers the author had. However, when I follow your instructions exactly as you state- it makes the block disappear. That's with both adding in the Grouping field, or leaving it out. Any suggestions?  Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Holy crap this is a tricky problem! I've made a blog post about it for D7: http://www.leesome.com/blog/2013/02/18/creating-following-and-followers-tabs-with-flags-in-drupal-7/

Basically reversing the output has to do with linking or not linking the uid Contextual Filter to the relationship